# How to flip N percent of enreries of binary matrix in R?

Tags: r

I have binary matrix A and I want to randomly change 20 percent of zero entries of it to 1. 
Can someone can help me with this?

Comment: Is there any limitation by column?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
m <- matrix(seq(1:100), nrow = 20, ncol = 5)
m[sample(length(m), round(length(m) * 0.2))] <- 0
```

Comment: this really depend on the dimensions of the matrix, why the hard-coded 20?

Comment: I showed the technique. It can be modified to whatever specific criteria necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

## Test data

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- sample(0:1, 40, replace = TRUE)
mat <- matrix(dat, nrow = 5) # 5x8 sample Matrix
```

## Actual code

```
ind <- which(mat == 0) # Gives you the indices of all zeros in the matrix
ind_to_change <- sample(ind, floor(length(ind)*0.2)) # sample 20% of the indices
mat[ind_to_change] <- 1 # set the samples indices to 1
```

Answer (score 2):

We can try

```
i1 <- m1==0
m1[sample(which(i1), round(sum(i1)*0.20))] <- 1
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
m1 <- matrix(sample(0:1, 5*4, replace=TRUE), ncol=5)
```